# Apache Total redirect with vhost to https expect one location

Tags: linux, apache, https

How to redirect traffic to https with virtual host settings expect one location.

One location I need to have "http" http://www.example.com/myhttplocation/

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RewriteRule` to do this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/myhttplocation
RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Add the above to your `VirutalHost` and make sure `mod_rewrite` is enabled